# Error in mesh(X,Y,Z) in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

This is my code:

```
load mwe16_2.dat;
x = mwe16_2(:,1);     % x contains the 1st column(500 values) of ‘mwe16_2’
y = mwe16_2(:,2);     % y contains the 2nd column (500 values)of ‘mwe16_2’
z = mwe16_2(:,3);     % z contains the 3rd column(500 values) of ‘mwe16_2’
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid (x, y, z);
mesh (X, Y, Z)
```

While running the code it is showing the error:

```
*Error in plot3_d (line 13) mesh(X,Y,Z) in Matlab*
```

Can someone say the reason for the error and how to correct it?

Comment: Some example data and possibly the full error message (as the one provided strikes me heavily edited) would help us help you greatly.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

[`[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z)`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) produces three 3D arrays from `x`, `y` and `z` vectors. Now if you take a look at [`mesh`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) you will see that you are not providing this function with proper input.

If you want to illustrate the set of points defined by three vectors of `x`, `y` and `z`, you can consider using [`scatter3`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html):

```
figure; scatter3(x, y, z)
```

Comment: thank you erfan for the idea it works but my idea is to plot something surface Plots with surf or sftool

Comment: When I try with those the problem is with the z not defined as a matrix. Is there a possibility to convert it? or is there a technique to plot the scattered plot to a continues surface?

Comment: In `surf` you need one _independent_ value for `z` per pair of `x` and `y`. It means you need 500 x 500 = 250000 independent data points in `z`, but you only have 500. You can interpolate though; [Here you can see how.](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/11475-surface-fit-of-a-3d-scatter-plot)